# Getting an error when adding an argument to kwargs

Tags: python, django, keyword-argument, python-decorators

So I'm trying to make a decorator for my django view and I have it sort of working. The decorator looks like

```
# Decorator for the function - update(request, extra=None)
def check_super(view):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        status = supercheck(request)

        if status=="USER":
            raise PermissionDenied
        else:
            args = [a for a in args]
            kwargs = dict((k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items())
            kwargs.update({'status':status})    # Offending line
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Basically I do a check with the supercheck function and I want to pass the result of that as another argument to my function but the line stated above results in the error

```
update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status'
```

kwargs is just a dictionary, right? So I should be able to add new bindings to it like that but it keeps giving me that error. Doing it this way also results in the same errror

```
kwargs['status']=status
```

Comment: Is the function you're wrapping also called "update". I think the offending line is where you call view() below the line you've marked. The "update" function in your first line comment does not accept a kwarg called "status"

Comment: Yeah, the function I'm wrapping is called update. I thought the whole point of passing in kwargs like I did in the return statement in wrapper() was so that I could add arbitrary arguments to it

Comment: A function ``f(**kwargs)`` can accept any arbitrary number of keyword args, but ``update(extra=None)`` only expects one keyword argument.

Comment: Perhaps try rw_kwargs = copy.copy(kwargs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah, I figured it out. Turns out all I had to do was make sure the original function took *args and **kwargs, which is much easier to generalize (since I don't know how these functions will be)

So my function update() now has the signature

```
update(request, extra=None, *args, **kwargs)
```

And I can pass in "arbitrary" keywords by updating kwargs before I wrap it. Thanks for the clarification. The comments helped me narrow down what the issue was!

The only caveat is that I access status in the update function with

```
kwargs['status']
```

instead of just

```
status
```

Which isn't too bad

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you're getting that -- I can't reproduce it on my machine.

That said, the easiest way to do what you want is to forget the mucking about with args and kwargs and just do

```
else:
    return view(request, *args, status=status, **kwargs)
```

assuming you *know* `view` takes an argument called 'status'. (If it doesn't, as John Spong said, well, there's your problem.)

[Here's a bit more on *args, **kwargs, and `**` in functions.](http://agiliq.com/blog/2012/06/understanding-args-and-kwargs/)

That said, it looks like all you want to do is check that the user passes your `supercheck` function. Check out the [`@user_passes_test` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) - it does exactly what you want.

Comment: The problem is that the original view doesn't take "status". That's why I tried including it in kwargs but it doesn't seem to let me

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that with kwargs -- you can't just arbitrarily pass arguments like that. Sorry! That said, there is a much easier way to do what you want -- check incoming edit.